# p5.js - achieving smooth animation with draw function

Tags: javascript, animation, p5.js

I am making a Monopoly style game written in javascript (Using the p5.js library). I am trying to create an animation of a card, using `rect`, sliding on top of a 2d object with a fixed width and height. Here are my 3 functions that show my thought process:

**card_property.js:**

```
function PropertyCard(posX, posY, width, height, property){
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.posX = posX;
  this.posY = posY;
  this.property = property;

  this.display = function(){
    rect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
  };
  this.update = function(){
      // not sure if I need to use this
  };
}
```

This is a snippet of my `draw` function (p5.js function which is invoked continuously unless conditional logic is used or a p5.js `noLoop` function is called) inside of my **game.js:**

```
var propCards = []
...
function draw(){
  ...
  for (var j = propCards.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
    frameRate(10)
    console.log(propCards)
    while (propCards[j].posX > 90){
      propCards[j].display();
      propCards[j].posX -= 5;
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, this function creates an instance of the property card that I'm trying to animate:

```
function addCard(property){
  propCard = new PropertyCard(680, 760, 20, 40, property);
  propCards.push(propCard);
}
```

When I try to create the animation, I end up rendering a static image that shows the cards overlapping each other across descending `x` values. How can I get the card to slide over my created rectangle and stop at a certain point? The picture below shows what I am seeing:

[image: Card animation attempt]

Comment: redraw the background every frame in draw?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of random snippets from your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

"Draw" displays what you program into it at the end of the function.

So what your doing is drawing multiple rectangles in the same frame.

What you have to do is make something that calculates where to put the rectangle each iteration of draw.

eg:

```
animationframe = 0

// draw function
// when you want the animation do: animationframe = distancetogo / 5
if (animationframe>0){
  for (var j = propCards.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
    propCards[j].posX -= 5;
    propCards[j].display();
  }
}
```